# I am trying to test my iPhone application on my device and I am getting debugging errors (Program Received SIGABRT) xcode 4.2

Tags: iphone, ios5, xcode4.2

I have an iPhone application in xcode 4.2 that runs fine on the iPhone 5.0 simulator, but when I try to run the application to my iPhone, it spits out the error: Program Received Signal "SIGABRT".

This is what the debugger shows:

[image: 14 main]

[image: 13UIApplicationMain]

[image: 0__pthread_kill]

I don't understand why the application would work fine on the simulator, but crash during the test run on my device?  Do you see what could be the problem?  I am not too familiar with debugging application

EDIT:  I'm continuing to have problems with this.  I tried following the instructions of the commenter below, but it did not work.  Please let me know what I need to get this to run successful on my phone based on these error reports.  Again, it runs fine in the simulator.

Answer (score 0):

1. In `project info -->Build Settings-->Valid Architectures`, change it to Armv6,Armv7 and make a new build.
2. Clean all targets, move old build to trash.
3. Make another buld with with Armv6 alone.
4. Run the code in the device.

Comment: I'm sorry, I do not understand what this means... "makin build"?

Comment: in project info -->Build Settings-->Valid Architectures .....Change it to Armv6,Armv7 and make new build.....and then make another buld with with Armv6 alone....

Comment: This didn't solve the problem, it just didn't run and spat out the error when I used a build with Armv6 alone...any other ideas?

Comment: @iAnirudh.. Thanks for your help but if you have any updates for your answer please update your answer instead comment.